# Update two columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

This is the table of data that I need to change.

```
SELECT appId, categoryID, categoryName, classdesc
FROM apps JOIN appsCategories USING(appID)
JOIN categories USING (categoryID)
JOIN classes USING (classID)
WHERE classDesc = "Auto"
```

which returns something like this:

```
appid         categoryID         categoryName        classDesc

400           100                Public              AUTO
405           101                Business            AUTO
410           102                Auto                AUTO
415           102                Auto                AUTO
```

I want to update my table so that all data below is updated to have a categoryName of Auto with the categoryID of 102. I need to use the Select statement above somehow but am unsure how to update both columns. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: consider providing an sqlfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are just wanting to update these 2 columns for every row in your table, this should work.

```
UPDATE apps a
JOIN appsCategories b
    ON a.appID = b.appID             //Whatever your keys are
JOIN categories c
    ON b.categoryID = c.categoryID   //Whatever your keys are
JOIN classes d
    ON c.classID = d.classID         //Whatever your keys are
SET categoryID='102', categoryName='Auto'
WHERE classDesc = "Auto"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's almost exactly what I was looking for.